# requestAnimationFrame, не получается зациклить

Tags: javascript, анимация, дата

Модернизирую найденный код. В оригинале клочья тумана проходят снизу вверх по canvas, и исчезают. Я пытаюсь добиться, чтобы ставшая max высота установилась в 0 (точнее наоборот, идем снизу вверх), и анимация зациклилась. Я пока не до конца поняла природу переменной `var td = new Date().getTime() - p.start;` Математически это вообще (-delay), но переменная постоянно растет (повязанна на реальном времени?)

```
if (p.newTop < 0)

    {   
        newTop = 100;
    }
```

Переместить в координату 100 (100 чисто для наглядности) получилось. А вот "обнулить" td, чтобы присвоить ее newTop для нового витка, не получается.

```js
const TIMEOUT = 40;
var stTime = 0;
canvasWidth = 1600;
canvasHeight = 200;
pCount = 0;
pCollection = new Array();
var puffs = 1;
var particlesPerPuff = 50; //2000
var img = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/85280/smoke2.png';
var smokeImage = new Image();
smokeImage.src = img;

for (var i1 = 0; i1 < puffs; i1++) {
  var puffDelay = i1 * 1500;
  for (var i2 = 0; i2 < particlesPerPuff; i2++) {
    addNewParticle((i2 * 50) + puffDelay);
  }
}

draw(new Date().getTime(), 3000);

function addNewParticle(delay) {
  var p = {};
  p.top = canvasHeight;
  p.left = randBetween(-200, 800);
  p.start = new Date().getTime() + delay;
  p.life = 8000;
  p.speedUp = 30;
  p.speedRight = randBetween(0, 20);
  p.startOpacity = .3
  p.newTop = p.top;
  p.newLeft = p.left;
  p.size = 200;
  p.growth = 10;

  pCollection[pCount] = p;
  pCount++;
}

function draw(time) {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

  for (let i = 0; i < pCount; i++) {
    var p = pCollection[i];
    var td = new Date().getTime() - p.start;
    console.log(td);
    var frac = td / p.life
    var newTop = p.top - (p.speedUp * (td / 1000));
    var newLeft = p.left + (p.speedRight * (td / 1000));
    var newOpacity = Math.max(p.startOpacity * (1), 0);
    //var newOpacity = Math.max(p.startOpacity * (1-frac),0);
    var newSize = p.size + (p.growth * (td / 1000));
    p.newTop = newTop;
    p.newLeft = newLeft;


    if (p.newTop < 0) {
      //td = new Date().getTime() - p.start;
      newTop = 100;
    }


    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(150,150,150,' + newOpacity + ')';
    ctx.globalAlpha = newOpacity;
    ctx.drawImage(smokeImage, newLeft, newTop, newSize, newSize);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function randBetween(n1, n2) {
  var r = (Math.random() * (n2 - n1)) + n1;
  return r;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: black url(https://s.cdpn.io/16327/texture_bg.jpg) no-repeat 50% 0px;
}

#myCanvas {
  height: 300px;
  width: 2400px;
  max-width: 99%;
  min-width: 800px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

#house {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 40%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" height="200" width="800"></canvas>
```

```
https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/ut42nb5e/2/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Логика работы анимации в вашем примере такая:

1. Создается элемент `Particle`. Ему, помимо прочих свойств, устанавливается время создания `p.start = new Date().getTime() + delay`,

   - `new Date().getTime()` - текущее время в миллисекундах
   - `delay` - задержка появления
2. Затем, во время отрисовки элемента высчитывается его положение `var newTop = p.top - (p.speedUp * (td / 1000));`

   - `p.top` - начальное положение
   - `p.speedUp` - скорость всплытия
   - `td`  - разница во времени в миллисекундах между текущим временем и временем начала `var td = new Date().getTime() - p.start`.

В итоге мы видим, что положение элемента в формуле `var newTop = p.top - (p.speedUp * (td / 1000));` зависит от начального положения(`p.top`), скорости(`p.speedUp`) и разницы времени(`td`). 
Переменные начального положения(`p.top`) и скорости(`p.speedUp`) не меняются - они константа для элемента.

Следовательно, положение элемента зависит от времени(`td`). Значит, вам надо поменять начальное значение времени, что бы задать положение элементу. Значит вам надо написать код `p.start = new Date().getTime()`.

Пример внизу.

```js
const TIMEOUT = 40;
var stTime = 0;
canvasWidth = 1600;
canvasHeight = 200;
pCount = 0;
pCollection = new Array();
var puffs = 1;
var particlesPerPuff = 50; //2000
var img = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/85280/smoke2.png';
var smokeImage = new Image();
smokeImage.src = img;

for (var i1 = 0; i1 < puffs; i1++) {
  var puffDelay = i1 * 1500;
  for (var i2 = 0; i2 < particlesPerPuff; i2++) {
    addNewParticle((i2 * 50) + puffDelay);
  }
}

draw(new Date().getTime(), 3000);

function addNewParticle(delay) {
  var p = {};
  p.top = canvasHeight;
  p.left = randBetween(-200, 800);
  p.start = new Date().getTime() + delay;
  p.life = 8000;
  p.speedUp = randBetween(10, 40); // делаем разную скорость, чтобы смотрелось красивее
  p.speedRight = randBetween(0, 20);
  p.startOpacity = .3
  p.newTop = p.top;
  p.newLeft = p.left;
  p.size = 200;
  p.growth = 10;

  pCollection[pCount] = p;
  pCount++;
}

function draw(time) {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

  for (let i = 0; i < pCount; i++) {
    var p = pCollection[i];
    var td = new Date().getTime() - p.start;
    var frac = td / p.life
    var newTop = p.top - (p.speedUp * (td / 1000));
    var newLeft = p.left + (p.speedRight * (td / 1000));
    var newOpacity = Math.max(p.startOpacity * (1), 0);
    //var newOpacity = Math.max(p.startOpacity * (1-frac),0);
    var newSize = p.size + (p.growth * (td / 1000));

    if (newTop <= 0) {
      p.start = new Date().getTime(); // обнуляем начальное время анимации start
    }


    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(150,150,150,' + newOpacity + ')';
    ctx.globalAlpha = newOpacity;
    ctx.drawImage(smokeImage, newLeft, newTop, newSize, newSize);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function randBetween(n1, n2) {
  var r = (Math.random() * (n2 - n1)) + n1;
  return r;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: black url(https://s.cdpn.io/16327/texture_bg.jpg) no-repeat 50% 0px;
}

#myCanvas {
  height: 300px;
  width: 2400px;
  max-width: 99%;
  min-width: 800px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

#house {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 40%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" height="200" width="800"></canvas>
```